# centralize images in div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `div` that can contain anywhere from one to four images. If there are less than four images, they get aligned to the left. I want to align them in the center of the containing `div` so that the image list is centered no matter how many images there are.

Here is my current code:

```
<div id="bigImg" {if $ads_settings.enable_video && $listing.enable_video && $listing.video}style="display: none;"{/if}>
    <center>
        <a href="{$live_site}/images/listings/{$listing.images[0].picture}" class="thickbox" rel="image_gallery">
            <img src="{$live_site}/images/listings/bigThmb/{$listing.images[0].picture}" class="pic" onmouseover="this.className='pic_over';" onmouseout="this.className='pic'" alt="{$listing.title|strip_tags:false}" />
        </a>
    </center>
</div>
```

The site I want this to work on can be found [here](http://kbay.in/details.php?id=82).

Comment: Please take a few minutes to re-read your question before posting. If you [look at the revisions](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/7353960/revisions), there was quite a lot that had to be rectified.

Comment: You gave a link and asked you need such design. Don't you know `Right click -> View source`

Answer (score 1):

Add the css-style `margin: 0 auto;` to your div `#bigImg`. This centers the contents.

Answer (score 1):

add this to css stylesheet

```
 .bigimg div {margin: 0 auto;}
 .bigimg div img {text-align: center; float: left;}
```

Add class and replace < center > tags with div as per bellow:

```
<div id="bigImg" class="bigimg" {if $ads_settings.enable_video && $listing.enable_video &&    $listing.video}style="display: none;"{/if}>
 <div>
    <a href="{$live_site}/images/listings/{$listing.images[0].picture}" class="thickbox" rel="image_gallery">
        <img src="{$live_site}/images/listings/bigThmb/{$listing.images[0].picture}" class="pic" onmouseover="this.className='pic_over';" onmouseout="this.className='pic'" alt="{$listing.title|strip_tags:false}" />
    </a>
    </div>
    </div>
```